# Add and count object in cookie javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm creating `Add to cart` module. I have `Add to cart` button, when the user click on it, then it will register `JSON data` of the item to cookie.

This is the example of the item object:

```
item =
     {
     DepartmentID :56,
     CategoryID:117,
     BrandID:19,
     BrandImage:"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
     BrandName:"General",
     Quantity:5,
     ID:706
     };
```

This is what I have done with cookie :

```
 $('#addToCart').click(function(){
     addObjToCookie('Cart',item);
 });

 function serializeObjToJSON(obj) {
    var json = $.toJSON(obj);
    return json;
 }

 function deserializeJSONToObj(json) {
    var obj = $.evalJSON(json);
    return obj;
 }
 function addObjToCookie(cookieName, obj) {
    var jsonObj = serializeObjToJSON(obj);
    $.cookie(cookieName, jsonObj);
 }

 function getDataFromCookie(cookieName){
    var obj = deserializeJSONToObj($.cookie(cookieName));
    return obj;
 }
```

1. How can I append the item object into `$(cookie('Cart'))` when user click on `Add to cart` button, with this format:

   ```
   [{"DepartmentID":56,"CategoryID":117,"BrandID":19,"BrandImage":"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","BrandName":"General","Quantity":5,"ID":706},
    {"DepartmentID":56,"CategoryID":117,"BrandID":19,"BrandImage":"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","BrandName":"General","Quantity":1,"ID":707}];
   ```
2. How to count the item in `Cart` cookie, in this example the result is `2`.
3. If the item in `Cart` is exist, then increase `Quantity` + 1.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are tweaks to answer 1 & 2

```
function addObjToCookie(cookieName, obj) {

  // When adding see what's in there
  var currentCart = getDataFromCookie( cookieName );

  // Add what's new
  currentCart.push( obj );

  // Save new contents
  $.cookie(cookieName, serializeObjToJSON( currentCart ) );
}

function getDataFromCookie(cookieName){

  var val = $.cookie(cookieName);

  // Make sure this returns something valid if it's not there
  if ( !val ) {
    return [];
  }

  // No need to save off something if you're not doing anything with it
  return deserializeJSONToObj( val );

}
```

As for #3, before actually saving the new cookie content, loop through the return value til you find a match and if you do modify that rather than pushing to the array.

If you try the loop and it doesn't work, please post your attempt. I like to help but not to write code from scratch, so you can learn some too.

Comment: I got one problem from `addObjToCookie()` function, In my current cookie cart contains 4 items and when I click to add the 5th item ,`addObjToCookie()` did not add the item to cookie.

Comment: Can you `console.log` `currentCart` and then what it's seralizing as? Then you can tell if it's giving the cookie the right information. Or actually.... if you were using the same cookies as before and it's saved on your machine, your cookie is a literal object like `{}` rather than array like `[]` so push won't work. Try clearing your existing cart.

Comment: This is what shows in my console when I clicked  `3 times` on button Add `[]

[Object { DepartmentID=56, CategoryID=117, BrandID=19, more...}]
[Object { DepartmentID=56, CategoryID=117, BrandID=19, more...}, Object { DepartmentID=56, CategoryID=117, BrandID=19, more...}]`

Comment: This is the format after serialization `[{"DepartmentID":...},
{"DepartmentID":...},
{"DepartmentID":...}]`

Comment: I am confused... if you see `[{...},{...},{...}]` that means 3 items are in the cart. What did you expect to see?

Comment: I clicked `Add` 4 or more than 4 times but it's show only 3 items in the cookie. Does it related to the maximum size that cookie can store only 4KB :/

Comment: Wouldn't that mean you have over 4 thousand characters in your JSON? I wasn't looking at what's in your object but I don't know why you'd want to store those `&nbsp;`s. You can also replace the strings with constants so your keys would only be one letter each.